# How to set EST Date as it is in DateTimePicker jquery without any conversion

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I have a python server which is return an EST time (for e.g 1420473600), when I am trying to set the same timestamp in my jquery Date Time Picker, it is not giving me an proper timing. Its showing an IST Time.

My code is as below.
//startTime and endTime are EST time stamps that I receive from Server.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker({  
    minDate:new Date(startTime*1000),
    maxDate:new Date(endTime*1000)
});
```

The datetimepicker converts is automatically to IST, I want to display the exact date as it is coming from Server without any conversion.

Comment: `1420473600` is not a EST time. It looks like a POSIX timestamp e.g., `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1420473600)` returns `datetime(2015, 1, 5, 16, 0)` i.e., the timestamp corresponds to `2015-01-05 16:00:00+00:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the "locale:'en'" option to the datetimepicker.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add it?

Comment: $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker({  
    minDate:new Date(startTime*1000),
    maxDate:new Date(endTime*1000),locale:'en'
});

Comment: If that doesnt work for your case, you can  read the "datepicker.regional" section on the link http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/